# How to find a vector component from another vector and the angle between the two vectors?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have two vectors, $(-2, 3, 1)$, and $(-1, 2, a)$. I know that the angle between these two vectors is $40^\circ$. How do I find *a*?

When I try to algebraically solve for a, I run into problems with the magnitudes. I understand that $X \cdot Y = |X| |Y| cos(Z)$. The problem is the magnitude of $Y$ in this case turns out to be $\sqrt{5 + a^2}$, and the dot product of $X$ and $Y$ is a + 8, so I can't figure out how to resolve the two to find a.

$a + 8 = \sqrt{14} \cdot \sqrt{5 + a^2} \cdot \cos(40^\circ)$

Comment: Welcome to math.se. [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Please include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Do you remember how angle between two vectors is *defined*?  It has something to do with dot product.  Now... describe the information you are given as a formula and algebraically solve for $a$.

Comment: When I try to algebraically solve for a, I run into problems with the magnitudes. I understand how X dot product Y = |X| * |Y| cos(Z). The problem is the magnitude of Y in this case turns out to be sqrt(5 + a^2), and the dot product of X and Y is a + 8, so I can't figure out how to resolve the two to find a.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable equation to solve for $a$.

Comment: @Tunococ How do I separate a in order to solve for a? I keep working with combining the square root and the expression on the left, but I keep getting seemingly inseparable results.

Comment: @JoshuaLike You might need to use the general formula for the quadratic equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the scalar product is defined as:

$$\mathbf{v}\bullet \mathbf{u}=vu\cos \theta\equiv v_xu_x+v_yu_y+v_zu_z$$

i.e.
$$\sqrt{14}\cdot \sqrt{5+a^2}=\frac{8+a}{\cos(40^{\circ})} \iff \sqrt{14\cdot (5+a^2)}=\frac{8+a}{\cos(40^{\circ})}$$

Hence, squaring LHS and RHS,

$$70\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ}\right)+14\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ }\right)a^2=64+16a+a^2$$

and the solution are (equation of second degree or quadratic formula), being the $70+14a^2>0, \, \forall a\in \Bbb R$,

$$a_1=\frac{-16+\sqrt{-3920\cos ^4\left(40^{\circ}\right)+3864\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ}\right)}}{2\left(1-14\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ}\right)\right)}, $$ $$a_2=-\frac{\sqrt{-3920\cos ^4\left(40^{\circ}\right)+3864\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ}\right)}+16}{2\left(1-14\cos ^2\left(40^{\circ }\right)\right)}$$

Comment: I am at this point myself, but I cannot separate a in order to find the possible values. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: @JoshuaLike I have finished the various edit. I hope that the steps are clear.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano! This was very helpful!

Comment: @JoshuaLike I am glady to help you. My best regards.